# En Query ing minds want to know

Tags: mysql, join, compare

I am trying to compare a mammoth table with over 300,000 rows and a much smaller table to see if data is in the big one and not in the little one. Here's my basic idea:

Code:

```
select TOAWorkOrdersNew.TechNum AS TOATechNum,
TOAWorkOrdersNew.FirstName AS TOAFirst,
TOAWorkOrdersNew.LastName AS TOALast,
TOAWorkOrdersNew.Title AS TOATitle,
TOAWorkOrdersNew.WorkDate AS TOAWorkDate,
Techs.TechNum AS TechNum,
Techs.FirstName AS FirstName,
Techs.LastName AS LastName,
Techs.JobDesc AS Job

from TOAWorkOrdersNew, Techs

where 

!!!!!    TOAWorkOrdersNew.WorkDate between '2013-05-15' and '2013-05-31' AND
TOAWorkOrdersNew.TechNum ***IS NOT FOUND INSIDE*** Techs.TechNum    !!!
```

Techs.TechNum is the unique key for Techs.

Thanks as always for the help,
tim

Comment: Look, you cannot really avoid learning SQL...

Comment: If the TechNum does not exist in the Techs table, how do you expect to return data from the techs table?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly....

Use a left join:

```
SELECT TOAWorkOrdersNew.TechNum AS TOATechNum,
    TOAWorkOrdersNew.FirstName AS TOAFirst,
    TOAWorkOrdersNew.LastName AS TOALast,
    TOAWorkOrdersNew.Title AS TOATitle,
    TOAWorkOrdersNew.WorkDate AS TOAWorkDate,
    Techs.TechNum AS TechNum,
    Techs.FirstName AS FirstName,
    Techs.LastName AS LastName,
    Techs.JobDesc AS Job
FROM Techs LEFT JOIN TOAWorkOrdersNew ON TOAWorkOrdersNew.TechNum = Techs.TechNum 
    AND TOAWorkOrdersNew.WorkDate BETWEEN '2013-05-15' and '2013-05-31' 
WHERE TOAWorkOrdersNew.TechNum IS NULL
```

To find all the ones that ARE in both tables you can change it to an inner join (getting rid of the IS NULL statement) or change the IS NULL to IS NOT NULL.

Really if you are only interested in finding records where the other table does NOT have a record in it, I'd expect something along the lines of:

```
SELECT t.firstName, t.lastName, t.jobDesc [job]
FROM Techs t
    LEFT JOIN TOAWorkOrdersNew toa ON toa.techNum = t.techNum 
       AND toa.WorkDate BETWEEN '2013-05-15' and '2013-05-31' 
WHERE toa.technum IS NULL
```

Comment: Don't put the `WorkDate` criteria in the `OUTER JOIN` -- it won't return the correct results.  Move that down into the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you want to return from your Techs table since you don't want the TechNum to exist in the Techs table.

Here's one option using an `OUTER JOIN` and checking for `NULL`:

```
select TOAWorkOrdersNew.TechNum AS TOATechNum,
    TOAWorkOrdersNew.FirstName AS TOAFirst,
    TOAWorkOrdersNew.LastName AS TOALast,
    TOAWorkOrdersNew.Title AS TOATitle,
    TOAWorkOrdersNew.WorkDate AS TOAWorkDate,
    Techs.TechNum AS TechNum,
    Techs.FirstName AS FirstName,
    Techs.LastName AS LastName,
    Techs.JobDesc AS Job
from TOAWorkOrdersNew left join 
    Techs on TOAWorkOrdersNew.TechNum = Techs.TechNum 
where Techs.TechNum is null 
    and TOAWorkOrdersNew.WorkDate between '2013-05-15' and '2013-05-31'
```

This will return all records from the TOAWorkOrdersNew where the technum does not exist in the techs table.  So the technum, firstname, lastname and job fields will all be `NULL`.

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)